# best way to backup and restore redis db when appendonly=yes

Tags: redis

I am very new to the Redis. I read other threads talk about that I can do `redis-cli save` to dump to .rdb. When restoring the database, I need to stop redis, change appendonly no in the config file, start redis, and run `redis-cli bgrewriteaof`. I need to automate the restore process with a script. Basically, the idea is to provide two scripts, one for backup and the other for restore, and let others to run the script to backup the current database, and restore in another server. The thing is our redis db is started by another application. I am hoping to gain more understanding to provide a better design. Here are my questions:

1. Not sure if this even works, but can I backup `appendonly.aof` directly and copy to another server instead of using `.rdb`?
2. Can I only change config file to `appendonly no` just for the backup. After I run `redis-cli bgrewriteaof`, I change the config file back to `appendonly yes`. Will this cause issues at the next redis-server restart? Will I lose data?
3. Is there other ways, no 3rd party application, to restore `.rdb` without manipulate config file, meaning not changing `appendonly yes`?
4. Say if I change config by running `redis-cli config set appendonly no` before I run `redis-cli save`, when I restore rdb file, would redis honor what's in the `.rdb` or the supplied config file when start the `redis-server`
5. If redis-server started as `appendonly yes`, would running `redis-cli bgrewriteaof` cause data lose?

Thanks in advance